# My employer incorrectly withheld FICA taxes and will refund them, can I still file my taxes using my W2 instead of W2C?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, form-w-2, payroll-taxes

As the title says, I am on student visa and my employer had incorrectly deducted fica taxes (medicaid and social security) from which I am exempt. As the first step is to contact the employer for a refund, I contacted them and they will be refunding the amount to me.  They said I can still file using my W2 instead of waiting for W2C, and since the deadline is near I want to avoid filing for an extension if possible. Can I still go ahead and file my taxes using my old W2?

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need to wait for the W2C. You *know* that the W2 is incorrect, you cannot knowingly submit a return with false information - it's a felony.

If you know the correct numbers that you expect to show up on W2C, you may want to consider [form 4852](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-4852), but it may backfire if you make a mistake, or if the IRS comes to the employer asking why they haven't issued W2C and it turns out that they have.

> and since the deadline is near I want to avoid filing for an extension if possible.

Why?

Comment: Generally it is customary to leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: +1, I would wait for the corrected W-2. Filling for an extension is less of a pain than having to amend your return. That having been said, since the FICA numbers don’t actually appear on the return, this shouldn’t actually affect the numbers on the 1040, right? Also, I think the odds of being charged with a felony are pretty low in this case. :)

Comment: @BenMiller being charged with a felony as not the same as committing a felony. The question on the immigration forms is whether you've ever *committed* a crime. For someone who's likely to be filling a lot of those, clear conscience is probably desired. As  to FICA - overcharged FICA taxes are credited on the tax return.

Comment: Point taken, but overcharged FICA taxes are only credited on the tax return if not reimbursed by the employer, which the OP expects to be. In any case, I fully agree that waiting to file is best.

Comment: @BenMiller+ only FICA overwithheld _because multiple employers together exceeded the 'wage base'_ (currently $160.2k) goes on the return. Withholding by _one_ employer above the limit, or improper withholding on a tax-nonresident as here, is refunded by that employer (only). _If_ you efile you don't even provide the W2 document -- but nonresident may not be able to efile.

Comment: That's a good point, you're correct of course.